# Chern-Weil theory and Weil homomorphism of principal bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, characteristic-classes, connections, principal-bundles, chern-classes

In Kobayashi and Nomizu's book Foundations of Differential geometry they introduce the concept of connection on a principal $G$ bundle. In this book, they use connection on a principal bundle to define (among other things) the characteristic classes of a (complex) vector bundle.

Let $G$ be a Lie group and  $P(M,G)$ be a principal $G$ bundle. Let $\Gamma$ be a connection on $P(M,G)$. This defines what is called a Weil homomorphism $I(G)\rightarrow H^*(M,\mathbb{R})$.

Given a complex vector bundle $E\rightarrow M$ with fibre $\mathbb{C}^r$ they consider associated principal $Gl(r,\mathbb{C})$ bundle $P\rightarrow M$ and define $k$-th Chern class of $E$ to be image of some element of $I(G)$.

But, it seems this Weil homomorphism can do more than constructing Characteristic classes.

> Is Weil homomorphism introduced (and used) only to construct Characteritic classes? If not, where else do we use this Weil homomorphism?

Edit (2 Nov 2019) : While searching for something, I have found what is called a **refined Chern-Weil homomorphism**, which has something to do with secondary characteristic classes.

Comment: Characteristic classes are not defined via Chern–Weil theory, rather the C–W theory gives another way to construct them. If you haven't seen it, the classic _Characteristic classes_ by Milnor and Stasheff is worth checking out.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I mean characteristic classes are also defined using connection and for this Chern-Weil homomorphism is used... I am not 100% sure if this also is grammatically correct :) please feel free to edit to make it look correct...

Comment: This is a comment in addition to David's comment. If you want to define Chern classes via C-W-theory you "only" get the images of the Chern classes defined in Milnor's book under the coefficient homomorphism $H^k(M;\mathbb Z) \to H^k(M;\mathbb R)$. In particular C-W cannot see torsion phenomena.

Comment: @PanagiotisKonstantis Is that so, I did not observe it.. can you kindly explain why it does not see torsion? Any reference would be helpful.. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik E.g. if a Chern class is a torsion element in $H^k(M;\mathbb Z)$ then it has to be mapped to zero under the homomorphism $H^k(M;\mathbb Z) \to H^k(M;\mathbb R)$ since the latter group do not contain torsion. But with C-W theory you construct exactly this zero class in $H^k(M;\mathbb R)$ (where $H^k(M;\mathbb R)$ is understood to be the deRham cohomology)

Comment: @PanagiotisKonstantis ok... That helps :) I will think and ask if I have any further question...